# SQL Where Expression in QueryOver API

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I am using the QueryOverApi, trying to use a SQL Expression in the where clause. I have basically:

```
        var query = CurrentSession.QueryOver<Appointment>(() => appt)
            .JoinAlias(() => appt.Work, () => work)
            .JoinAlias(()=>appt.Contact,()=>ct)
            .JoinAlias (()=>ct.Tags,()=>tag)
            .Where(Expression.Sql("(ct2_.OrganizationId in (SELECT...."))
```

This works but I have had to hardcode my alias ct2_. How can I figure out that nHibernate is going to alias my contact table as ct2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, at least in any official way. See the open issue here where someone has provided a patch: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1432